# How to arrange engine games?

Tags: engines, stockfish, leela

I have heard in various places that we can make engines play against each other from a certain given position. I want to know how exactly to do that. Is there a website where I can put a position and make Leela and Stockfish (14 or 15 preferably) play a position that I want them to play, or is it something only a few people have the advantage of doing?

Please let me know whether there are ways for me to arrange for such games.

Comment: You can arrange the matches with free engines but other people might have much more powerful computers.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

- https://github.com/cutechess/cutechess

You will see a sample usage where two engines are paired togerther:

> cutechess-cli -engine cmd=sloppy -engine cmd=sloppy -each proto=xboard
> tc=40/60 -rounds 10

Answer (score 2):

[Arena](http://www.playwitharena.de/) seems to be a good fit for what you want to do. You can install any engines you want, set up any position and make them play against each other using the Game->Demo command.

Comment: You can do this in ChessX too, and XBoard.