# 2 Chess engines versing eachother in scid

Tags: stockfish, scid, leela

How can I make 2 chess engines play against each other in Scid on serious game?

I remember I managed to do that one time, but this time, I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: Related (not a dupe): [How to arrange engine games?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/41219/26335)

Comment: The only way you can do that in SCID (at least in recent versions, idk if older versions allow you to do it) is adding moves manually and switching engines.